# Get the current view in scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a picture gallery with many pictures. I want to use lazy loading and only load the images that are visible in the screen. The gallery is inside a div becuase this whole gallery is a part of a bigger project.

**What I want**: Get the current scroll location of the div so I can check if the images are in view in the div.

**What I have**: I have it working on the full window scroll bar, I just need to get it changed to the div.

```
        var pItem = document.getElementsByClassName('progressive replace'), timer;

function inView() {
        var wT = window.pageYOffset, wB = wT + window.innerHeight, cRect, pT, pB, p = 0;
        while (p < pItem.length) {

            cRect = pItem[p].getBoundingClientRect();
            pT = wT + cRect.top;
            pB = pT + cRect.height;

            if (wT < pB && wB > pT) {
                loadFullImage(pItem[p]);
                pItem[p].classList.remove('replace');
            }
            else p++;
        }
    }
```

I need something like this:

```
function inView() {
        var wT = $('.image_view').pageYOffset, wB = wT + $('.image_view').innerHeight, cRect, pT, pB, p = 0;
        while (p < pItem.length) {

            cRect = pItem[p].getBoundingClientRect();
            pT = wT + cRect.top;
            pB = pT + cRect.height;

            if (wT < pB && wB > pT) {
                loadFullImage(pItem[p]);
                pItem[p].classList.remove('replace');
            }
            else p++;
        }
    }
```

The class `image_view` is the scrollable div with the images inside it.

Comment: try to use `.offset.top()` for element you have inside scrollable container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the current scroll value with jQuery and `scrolltop` like this;

```
$('#scrollableDiv').scrollTop();
```